# MVC2 html dropdownlist is invisible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am just trying to populate a html.dropdown list using mvc2 in VS2008.

But the control is not displayed at all.

Here is my code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    ViewData["Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    var mdl = new List<SelectListItem>();

    mdl.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = "1",
        Text = "Module One"
    });
    mdl.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = "2",
        Text = "Module Two"
    });
    ViewData["moduleList"] = new SelectList(mdl,"Value", "Text");

    return View("MainMenu");
}
```

and here is the markup

```
<div>
  <%Html.DropDownList("moduleList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["moduleList"]); %>
</div>
```

Where did i go wrong ?

Comment: Did you view the source on the rendered page?  Is the drop down there?

Comment: its best to store this stuff in a model, I have posted a complete example which is pastable below along with a bit of an explanation, I hope this helps.

Comment: No I dont see any dropdown in the source

Comment: solution added in my original answer which was downvoted hope this helps you can do this much more simply hope this helps you out, it does indeed not work the other way which I have never seen done before (which doesn't mean you can't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are best putting that stuff in your model so for example

in the controller

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        ViewData["Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var mdl = new List<SelectListItem>
                      {
                          new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Value = "1",
                                  Text = "Module One"
                              },
                          new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Value = "2",
                                  Text = "Module Two"
                              }
                      };

        ViewData["moduleList"] = new SelectList(mdl, "Value", "Text");

        var model = new HomeModel
                        {
                            SelectedItem = 1,
                            items = mdl
                        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

}

Now create the model

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class HomeModel
    {
        public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

your page will look like this on a test site

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.HomeModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>
    <div> 
  <%=Html.DropDownList("SelectedItem", Model.items)%>
    </div> 
</asp:Content>
```

Now an explanation, you have created a model for the view and this model is returned to the page by the controller the page is inheriting from a ViewPage which takes the generic argument of the model that was supplied to it by the controller

The markup is saying "give me a html drop down and mark the selected item as the first selected, the items come from the model (which is what your controller supplied it).

In the real world the data would come from your data layer and not directly in the controller (I like as little code in the controller as possible)

edit:

You have a typo for your example try this

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("moduleList") %>
```

Comment: this answer does not deserve a downvote it acheives exactly what the user wants and is a cleaner implementation

Comment: Thanks krystan i use models in other cases and it works fine. But that  does not explain the above problem. I mean technicaly it should work but it does not. why ? that is the question...

Comment: fixed answered question both ways, have a nice day :)

Comment: @Deb this edit is what you need. Good catch in your edit, I changed my down vote to an up vote. Used to razor syntax which behaves differently in this respect.

Comment: IMO mixing `ViewData` and the view model approach is worse then simply picking one or the other because you are then looking in different places for the data.

Comment: Totally agree craig but lets not get this to a chat (mods will can it), I use razor these days but remember doing something similar before :)

Comment: Actualy there are two typos, left an '=' sign and unnecessery ';' at the end.